# Conflict with the Jssor and PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, slider, conflict, pagespeed, jssor

I have a problem of conflict with the Jssor and PageSpeed​​. 
When I connect PageSpeed ​​the console returns me the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

and

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $JssorEventManager$ is not defined

How could I solve this?

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: My code is the same on the api page, when i'm develop in localhost, this work normally, but, when i make upload the code for web host, has a conflict with pagespeed. 
I was using: `<script src="jssor.slider.js"></script>`
Now I change for `<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>`
and work normally. But still appears "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

PS.: my english is too poor and I have no idea if I expressed it very well....

Comment: there is no $JssorEventManager$ in jssor slider minified code.

Comment: as jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.core.js + jssor.utils.js + jssor.sider.js), please make sure you get <script src="jssor.core.js"></script> and <script src="jssor.utils.js"></script> removed

Comment: Thanks, jssor's comment fixed it for me. That should be posted as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `<script src="jssor.core.js"></script>`, `<script src="jssor.utils.js"></script>` and `<script src="jssor.sider.js"></script>`

Added `<script src="jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>` and problem is solved.